# What is the best approach for Validator Exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, validation

Should I create a specialized Exception for each kind of validation, for sample:

```
public void doSomething(Text text) {
   if (!text.isAlphaNumeric()) throw new NonAlphaNumericException("Text should be alphanumeric");
   if (text.isBlank()) throw new BlankException("Text should not be empty or null");
   ...
}
```

or, should I do a generic exception like:

```
public void doSomething(Text text) {
   if (!text.isAlphaNumeric()) throw new TextValidationException("Text should be alphanumeric");
   if (text.isBlank()) throw new TextValidationException("Text should not be empty or null");
   ...
}
```

Comment: This would depend on what you are planning on doing with the Exception. More specific exceptions allow more specific behavior when caught.

Comment: How do you plan to use these exceptions?  How will they be caught?

Comment: There is no "should", it depends on your requirements. Personally, I think an exception per validation issue is extreme and I wouldn't do it, unless I had a genuine need to. I haven't had that need.

Comment: In addition, particularly if you'll be using hyper-granular exceptions, I'd wrap it up a layer deeper and have a collection of `validate` implementations that throw their respective exceptions to avoid large chunks of repetitive code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends by what you need to do with these exceptions.

Another way is to use an Hybrid approach: you create a main ExceptionType and some derived exceptions.

In this manner you Can choose what exception you want to raise/manage in a specific way. The others Can be managed in more general way.

It sounds like the difference between java.lang.Exception and other subtypes (eg. IOException etc...).

Answer (score 3):

If you use the first approach, then the caller can handle each exception separately:

```
try
{
    doSomething(new Text("blah blah"));
}
catch(NonAlphaNumericException e){/* do something */}
catch(BlankException e){/* do something else */}
```

Comment: +1 They can all share a common super class like TextValidationException and you get the best of both worlds. i.e. to can catch TextValidationException as well.